# Variable name in EL Expression 2.2

Tags: jsf, el

I feel a little dumb: I am using Primefaces on Tomcat 7 and would like to use those fancy new EL expressions to reduce some code clutter. I figured out how to do this in datatables but I can't get it to work otuside recurring structures which have those handy `var` attributes. How would I declare the EL parameter for `grantRole(String)` to be the value of the `inputText`?

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <h:outputText value="Name" />
    <p:inputText/>
    <p:commandButton value="Add" update="associatedPlayers" 
       action="#{permissionRoleDetailBean.grantRole(associatePlayerName)}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do so:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <h:outputText value="Name" />
    <p:inputText binding="#{playerName}" />
    <p:commandButton value="Add" update="associatedPlayers" 
       action="#{permissionRoleDetailBean.grantRole(playerName.value)}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

However, this makes no sense. The normal approach is the following:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <h:outputText value="Name" />
    <p:inputText value="#{permissionRoleDetailBean.playerName}" />
    <p:commandButton value="Add" update="associatedPlayers" 
       action="#{permissionRoleDetailBean.grantRole}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

with

```
private String playerName; // +getter+setter

public void grantRole() {
    System.out.println(playerName); // Look, it's already set by JSF.
}
```

Comment: I try to get rid of properties that are only used as arguments for other method calls. It seems to me that your second solution requires my bean to have a `playerName` property. Why would you prefer that?

Comment: You're losing the control over the model, you won't be able to preinitialize it for edit screens, for example.

Comment: Ah, thats a valid point of course. However, in this situation there will be no seperate edit screen.